# Extract variable from nested for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to loop through multiple files and extract a calculated variable from each as its own variable name (I.E. max_value[1], max_value[2], ...). Currently using a dictionary to store each variable.

```
### Create dictionary
max_value = dict()
### Loop through files using glob
for file in glob.glob('files'):
    ### Do calculations using file variables
    calculated_value = 10

    ### Store calculated value in dictionary
    for x in range(1,num_files+1):
        max_value[x] = calculated_value
```

However, the nested for loop overwrites the previous saved max_value with the calculated_value of the last file. How can I avoid rewriting each max_value in the dictionary from the last file's max_value?

Comment: Use *another* container as the dictionary value? It's hard to say much more, what exactly *do you want*?

Comment: Seems like the innermost loop is just writing `calculated_value` to every single key in `max_value`. What is the behaviour that you're looking for?

Comment: You are using a varibale name `num_files` that is never declared. What is that value for? And please show an example of the output you want. From reading this code it's not clear at all what you are trying to do. [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
### Create dictionary
max_value = dict()
### Loop through files using glob
for i, file in enumerate(glob.glob('files')):
    ### Do calculations using file variables
    calculated_value = 10

    ### Store calculated value in dictionary
    max_value[i] = calculated_value
```

Answer (score 0):

You never update num_files, so you keep overwriting your own data.